# Add loading spinner with R DataTable package

Tags: r, shiny, spinner, dt, css-loader

I tried using the cssloader package with the DT package but get the error

Warning: Error in datatable: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)

Is there another way to add a loading spinner that will work with renderDT ? 
Maybe a conditional panel that hides/shows?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please provide [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example for `DT` with `shinycssloaders`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinycssloaders)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12,withSpinner(DT::DTOutput('tbl'))))),
  server = function(input, output) {
    Sys.sleep(2)
    output$tbl = renderDT(
      iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Wow... I've been searching for this feature for months now. Thanks for providing a dynamic answer for replicating in any UI element.

Comment: DT has a loader image by default now